getting error 1054 unknown column 'b.password' in 'where clause'
I've upgraded from Joomlam3.10 to 4.4.5
I have EasySocial installed.
From the EasySocial Group list, clicking on any group results in an error:
The requested page can't be found.
1054 Unknown column 'b.password' in 'where clause'
I've been searching the web but haven't found the same exact error.
I have found a couple of errors that were very similar. The solutions there seemed to indicate going to Extensions > Manage > Database > fix.
In Joomla 4.4.5 I could find Maintenance:Database and there is a button to Update structure. So I selected the Joomla CMS file and clicked on the "Update structure" button.
This didn't fix the problem.
Has anyone else come across this error or have some guidance on how to fix please?
I've set Debug system to yes; server error reporting to maximum; and logging = almost everything.
I get this in public_html/administrator/logs/everything.php:
    #
    #<?php die('Forbidden.'); ?>
    #Date: 2024-07-13 00:03:28 UTC
    #Software: Joomla! 4.4.5 Stable [ Pamoja ] 28-May-2024 16:00 GMT
    
    #Fields: datetime   priority clientip   category    message
    2024-07-13T00:03:28+00:00   CRITICAL 61.68.179.171  error   Uncaught Throwable of type mysqli_sql_exception thrown with message "Unknown column 'b.password' in 'where clause'". 
Stack trace: 
    #0 [ROOT]/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliStatement.php(137): mysqli->prepare()
    #1 [ROOT]/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/Mysqli/MysqliDriver.php(1089): Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliStatement->__construct()
    #2 [ROOT]/libraries/vendor/joomla/database/src/DatabaseDriver.php(1900): Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliDriver->prepareStatement()
    #3 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/db/helpers/base.php(46): Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver->setQuery()
    #4 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/db/db.php(298): SocialDBHelper->__call()
    #5 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/models/photos.php(896): SocialDb->setQuery()
    #6 [ROOT]/media/com_easysocial/apps/group/photos/widgets/groups/view.html.php(129): EasySocialModelPhotos->getPhotos()
    #7 [ROOT]/media/com_easysocial/apps/group/photos/widgets/groups/view.html.php(91): PhotosWidgetsGroups->getPhotos()
    #8 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/apps/apps.php(231): PhotosWidgetsGroups->sidebarBottom()
    #9 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/themes/themes.php(484): SocialApps->renderWidgets()
    #10 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/modules/modules.php(506): SocialThemes->renderWidgets()
    #11 [ROOT]/modules/mod_easysocial_sidebar[TMP]l/group_item.php(49): SocialModules->render()
    #12 [ROOT]/modules/mod_easysocial_sidebar/adapters/groups.php(74): require('/home/famlyonl/...')
    #13 [ROOT]/modules/mod_easysocial_sidebar/adapters/groups.php(31): SocialSidebarGroups->renderItem()
    #14 [ROOT]/modules/mod_easysocial_sidebar/mod_easysocial_sidebar.php(48): SocialSidebarGroups->render()
    #15 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ModuleDispatcher.php(52): include('/home/famlyonl/...')
    #16 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Dispatcher/ModuleDispatcher.php(55): Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ModuleDispatcher::Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\{closure}()
    #17 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Helper/ModuleHelper.php(281): Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\ModuleDispatcher->dispatch()
    #18 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Helper/ModuleHelper.php(161): Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper::renderRawModule()
    #19 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Document/Renderer/Html/ModuleRenderer.php(99): Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper::renderModule()
    #20 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/themes/themes.php(410): Joomla\CMS\Document\Renderer\Html\ModuleRenderer->render()
    #21 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/themes/themes.php(331): SocialThemes->renderModule()
    #22 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/themes/wireframe/helpers/html/sidebar.php(16): SocialThemes->render()
    #23 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/template/template.php(273): include('/home/famlyonl/...')
    #24 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/themes/themes.php(226): SocialTemplate->parse()
    #25 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/template/helpers/html.php(412): SocialThemes->output()
    #26 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/template/template.php(376): ThemesHelperHTML->sidebar()
    #27 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/themes/wireframe/groups/item/default.php(20): SocialTemplate->html()
    #28 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/template/template.php(273): include('/home/famlyonl/...')
    #29 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/themes/themes.php(226): SocialTemplate->parse()
    #30 [ROOT]/administrator/components/com_easysocial/includes/views.php(290): SocialThemes->output()
    #31 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/views/views.php(245): EasySocialView->display()
    #32 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/views/groups/view.html.php(1034): EasySocialSiteView->display()
    #33 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/controllers/controller.php(145): EasySocialViewGroups->item()
    #34 [ROOT]/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php(693): EasySocialController->display()
    #35 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/controllers/controller.php(67): Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute()
    #36 [ROOT]/components/com_easysocial/easysocial.php(100): EasySocialController->execute()
    #37 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php(71): require_once('/home/famlyonl/...')
    #38 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Dispatcher/LegacyComponentDispatcher.php(73): Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher::Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\{closure}()
    #39 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(361): Joomla\CMS\Dispatcher\LegacyComponentDispatcher->dispatch()
    #40 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(208): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()
    #41 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/SiteApplication.php(249): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->dispatch()
    #42 [ROOT]/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(293): Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication->doExecute()
    #43 [ROOT]/includes/app.php(61): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
    #44 [ROOT]/index.php(32): require_once('/home/famlyonl/...')
    #45 {main}


The Maintenance:Database option for Joomla CMS is only going apply to database tables that are part of the core Joomla installation and has no affect, as you found out, on 3rd extensions. If there was an option there for EasySocial then you might have better luck in fixing the table.

If you go into Global Configuration and set Debug to Yes and Error Reporting to Maximum and you will get more details of where the error is actually occurring, even if just to confirm the issue is in an EasySocial extension or table. If you can update your original question with the stack trace that will be helpful.

Hi Irata, thanks for your response. I have updated my original question after changing nthe settings in Joomla Global Configuration. Is this what you were requiring? I'm not sure what a stack trace is. Also, I pasted the file details in the question as I couldn't find a way to add an attachmenty. Please let me know if you need more help. One other thing. I logged on as superuser and the error doesn't occur. However, the 1054 error occurs for all other access types.

Tony the issue is still looking like it is something to do with a table of the EasySocial extension is missing at least the field/column called password that maybe the result of failure during the upgrade process you went through. I don't use or have access to an Easy Social install to compare things but you may need to contact support at stackideas.com to see if they have a tool to repair their database table. If you are not familiar or comfortable with modifying database tables directly then you might have to call in some assistance.

The Stack Trace is what you have provided above, it is a 'stack' of each file that has been executed working backwards from the file where the error has occurred, #0, to the file that called it, #1, and the file that called #1 that is #2, and so on.  The number in the brackets , e.g. (269), is the line number in file a that invoked file b.

Hi Irata, thanks for the explanation, that was very helpful. I'll contact the EasySocial team to see if there's a way to repair the table. I had thoughtt that it was some kind of access level problem as the issue doesn't occur when I log in as the super user. However, the error message is very clear. Thanks again.

Hi Irata, the EasySocial team were able to direct me to the table causing the issue. They also gave me the ALTER TABLE command to fix the issue. Thanks again for your help.
